# Secured boot on kubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, 22.04, security, bios

I upgraded Kubuntu 20.04 to Kubuntu 22.04 on Aspire 5 and touchpad became unresponsive. So I decide reinstall Kubuntu, created boot drive, set it first priority boot in BIOS but the system wouldn't allow it. The message "Security boot failed". However, Security boot cannot be turned off -- BIOS doesn't present that option. I found how to disable Security boot mode from the command line. It "worked" in a weird way while I tried to boot from the external drive: First, read "Security boot failed" and then "Continue to boot insecurely" and started the same Kubuntu 22.04. BIOS showed Security boot mode Enabled. So, as of the moment There is no way to ever change OS on this laptop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in any ways an expert, but BIOS doesn't allow changing Security Boot, unless you did set a supervisor password. In Bios go to Security.
Then set supervisor password. Now you can change Secure Boot.
Just change everything in the initial setting after your installation.
Change Secure Boot to enabled, then clear the supervisor password. To clear the supervisor password, first just enter the old password and then leave the new one blank (hit Enter two times)

Comment: This is not true of all make and models of computers.